# Multiple instances breaks WordPress shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, ob-get-contents

I wrote a shortcode that displayed author profiles based on id. For example [user-profile id="1"] would display the profile block defined in [user-profile.php](http://dev.airve.com/code/user-profile_20110605.txt) for author 1. It worked (even with multiple instances on the same page).

```
function user_profile( $atts, $content = null ) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array('id' => ''), $atts));
    include 'user-profile.php';
}
```

...except the shortcode output was showing up before other entry content regardless of its place in the code. To solve this I added this fix:

```
function user_profile( $atts, $content = null ) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array('id' => ''), $atts));
    function get_user_profile() { include 'user-profile.php'; }
    ob_start();
    get_user_profile();
    $output_string = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output_string;
}
```

...which worked to solve the positioning problem but broke multiple instances of the shortcode. [user-profile id="1"] works but [user-profile id="1"] [user-profile id="2"] breaks it—the page just stops loading at that point.

How can I modify this to allow multiple instances?

Comment: what error you getting if any? i suspect its due to defining a function in function, have you tried putting `function get_user_profile(){}` out of the user_profile function

Comment: please move your comment to answer section, and mark it as the right answer.

Comment: @silent Thanks and thanks, yea I tried doing that before but it said I couldn't do it for 8 hrs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! I updated the code in [user-profile.php](http://dev.airve.com/code/user-profile_20110606.txt) code so that it was all PHP and did not use any echos. Then I changed the shortcode function to:

```
function user_profile( $atts, $content = null ) {
    global $post;
    extract(shortcode_atts(array('id' => ''), $atts));
    include 'user-profile.php';
    return $user_hcard;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
[user-profile id="1"][/user-profile] [user-profile id="2"][/user-profile]
```